# Spring JPA OneToOne mapped entities not behaving properly in Transactional tests

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit

I'm writing tests for some logic around some Spring JpaRepositories I have created. I'm doing this using the embedded in-memory H2 database. I'm seeing a weird scenario where my OneToOne mapped entities aren't behaving properly.

My `User` and `SSOUser` are entities joined with a OneToOne relationship, with the `SSOUser` entity simply having additional metadata for a user that is signing in with our SSO solution. In the test code I am providing below, when `@Transactional` is NOT applied, everything works. When I do add `@Transactional`, however, it fails on the commented line:

```
@Test
public void test_saveFindUserAndSsoUser() throws Exception {
    User user = mockUser();
    user = userCarrierRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
    SSOUser ssoUser = new SSOUser();
    ssoUser.setUser(user);
    ssoUser = ssoUserRepository.saveAndFlush(ssoUser);

    assertNotNull(user.getId());
    assertNotNull(ssoUser.getId());
    SSOUser ssoUser2 = ssoUserRepository.findById(ssoUser.getId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Could not find SSO User by ID"));
    assertThat(ssoUser2, allOf(
            hasProperty("id", equalTo(ssoUser.getId())),
            hasProperty("user", notNullValue())
    ));
    assertThat(ssoUser2.getUser(), hasProperty("id", equalTo(user.getId())));

    final User user2 = userCarrierRepository.findById(user.getId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Could not find User by ID"));

    assertThat(user2, allOf(
            hasProperty("id", equalTo(user.getId())),
            hasProperty("ssoUser", notNullValue()) // FAILS HERE BECAUSE ssoUser IS NULL
    ));
    assertThat(user2.getSsoUser(), hasProperty("id", equalTo(ssoUser.getId())));
}
```

The User entity, using Lombok, is:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private SSOUser ssoUser;

    public boolean isSSOUser() {
        return ssoUser != null;
    }
}
```

The SSOUser entity, using Lombok, is:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "sso_user")
public class SSOUser implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

}
```

And here is the SQL DDL statement to add the appropriate table to our database:

```
CREATE TABLE sso_user (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES public.user (id)
);
```

So, back to the original code, the `User` entity is being saved with the `ssoUser` field as null. However, the `SSOUser` entity is being saved with a valid `User` entity. I would expect the `sso_user` table to contain the appropriate value in the `user_id` column.

Because of the fact that the data is correct in the `sso_user` table, I would expect `userCarrierRepository.findById(...)` to return a `User` with the joined `ssoUser` included, just as I would expect `sslUserRepository.findById(...)` to return the `SSOUser` with the joined `user` included.

However, that is not what is happening. Only the SSOUser is being returned with the joined entity, the User is not.

Again, this only happens if I add @Transactional to the code provided here. Without that annotation, everything works as I would expect.

Comment: What about the last test if you comment the one that is failing?

Comment: As a note, the idea behind JPA is that you shouldn't need to be handling the "SSO" part separately. You probably don't even need the SSO repository: `SELECT User u FROM User WHERE u.ssoUser.someValue = ?`

Comment: That would not work. The long term goal is to use the separate SSOUser entity to store additional metadata that we will need in the future. Please answer the original question about the behavior I am seeing. Thank you.